# Multiple cursors in C#

Tags: c#, cursor

I'm working in an OpenSim project and I have some troubles.

I have an HMD wich will work for the view of the user, and a glove with a tracker for moving the objects, the problem is both of them are treated as mouse movement, so when i move the glove, looks like I'm moving my head.

I think that that I could make two cursors, one for the HMD and the other for the glove, but I can't find a way to do that.

So I hope you can help to find a way for it. (Having 2 cursors)

I already tried with the SDK of Windows for that, but it didn't work.

Comment: When you wrote `SDK of Windows`, did you mean this one? http://www.microsoft.com/multipoint/mouse-sdk/

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Type "multiple mice" in the Search box at the upper right of this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend wrote an article on his blog explaining how to do this. Its kinda long so I can't paste whole text here.

http://www.asawicki.info/news_1533_handling_multiple_mice_with_raw_input.html